# Get element text with a partial string match using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract the text from within a `<strong>` tag that is deeply nested in the HTML content of this webpage: https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9854612

For example:

[image]

The strong tag is the only one on the webpage that will contain the string 'cubic meters'.

My objective is to extract the entire text, i.e., "138124 cubic meters Liquid Gas". When I try the following, I get an error:

```
url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9854612"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("//strong[contains(text(),'cubic meters')]").text
print(element)
```

Error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"//strong[contains(text(),'cubic meters')]"}

What am I doing wrong here?

The following also throws an error:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'cubic')]").text
```

Comment: You're using the wrong method; `find_element_by_link_text` is used when you need to look for an [hyperlink with the specified text inside the link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text).

Comment: I have also tried `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'cubic')]").text`

Comment: first you could check what you have in `driver.page_source` - maybe you get different HTML without `strong`. OR maybe first get all `strong` and display text for all of them to see if there is text with `cubic`

Comment: code works for me with `Firefox()` but not with `Chrome()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works on `Firefox()`, but not on `Chrome()`.

The page uses *lazy loading*, so you have to scroll to *Summary* and then it loads the text with the expected *strong*.

I used a little slower method - I search all
elements with `class='lazyload-wrapper`, and in the loop scroll to the item and check if there is *strong*. If there isn't any *strong*, then I scroll to the next `class='lazyload-wrapper`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9854612"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']")

for number, item in enumerate(elements):
    print('--- item', number, '---')
    #print('--- before ---')
    #print(item.text)

    actions.move_to_element(item).perform()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #print('--- after ---')
    #print(item.text)

    try:
        strong = item.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(text(), 'cubic')]")
        print(strong.text)
        break
    except Exception as ex:
        #print(ex)
        pass
```

Result:

```
--- item 0 ---
--- item 1 ---
--- item 2 ---
173400 cubic meters Liquid Gas
```

The result shows that I could use `elements[2]` to skip two elements, but I wasn't sure if this text will be always in the third element.

---

Before I created my version I tested other versions and here is the full working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9854612"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

def test0():
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong")
    for item in elements:
        print(item.text)

    print('---')

    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(text(), 'cubic')]")
    print(item.text)

def test1a():
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-body1')][last()]//div")
    actions.move_to_element(element).build().perform()
    text = element.text
    print(text)

def test1b():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-body1')][last()]//strong").text
    print(text)

def test2():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    soup.find_all(string=re.compile(r"\d+ cubic meters"))

def test3():
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']")

    for number, item in enumerate(elements, 1):
        print('--- number', number, '---')
        #print('--- before ---')
        #print(item.text)

        actions.move_to_element(item).perform()
        time.sleep(0.1)

        #print('--- after ---')
        #print(item.text)

        try:
            strong = item.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(text(), 'cubic')]")
            print(strong.text)
            break
        except Exception as ex:
            #print(ex)
            pass

#test0()
#test1a()
#test1b()
#test2()
test3()
```

Comment: great intro to handling lazy loading!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) for this, and more precisely [the `string` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument); from the documentation, "you can search for strings instead of tags".

As an argument, you can also pass a regex pattern.

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find_all(string=re.compile(r"\d+ cubic meters"))
['173400 cubic meters Liquid Gas']
```

If you're sure there is only one result, or you need just the first, you can also use `find` instead of `find_all`.

Comment: your code works for me with `Firefox()` but not with `Chrome()` - and this is the problem. Original code also works with `Firefox()` but not with `Chrome()` - so it can means OP uses `Chrome()`

Comment: What should change? The search is made on a string, so a different browser shouldn't change anything; I even tried executing this snippet from a Chrome page source, and everything worked.

Comment: maybe it depends on window size, browser version, font size, etc. Code uses JavaScript to load text only when it is visible - `lazy loading` (you can even see element with `class=lazyload-wraper"`) - and on Chrome I have to scroll window to see text and then it adds it to HTML. For some reason Firefox loads all at once - at least my Firefox load it.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression is correct and works in Chrome. You get `NoSuchElementException`, because the element is not loaded within the 3 seconds you wait and does not exist.

To wait for the element, use the `WebDriverWait` class. It waits explicitly for a specific condition of the element, and in your case presents is enough.

In the code below, Selenium will wait for the element to be presented in the HTML for 10 seconds, polling every 500 milliseconds. You can read about `WebDriverWait` and conditions [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Some useful information: 
Not visible elements return an empty string. In such a case you need to wait for the visibility of the element, or if the element requires a scroll to scroll to it (example added).

You can also get the text from a not-visible element using JavaScript.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9854612"
locator = "//strong[contains(text(),'cubic meters')]"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:  # Type: webdriver
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    driver.get(url)

    cubic = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator)))  # Type: WebElement
    print(cubic.text)

    # The below examples are just for information
    # and are not needed for the case

    # Example with scroll. Scroll to the element to make it visible
    cubic.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    print(cubic.text)

    # Example using JavaScript. Works for not visible elements.
    text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].textContent", cubic)
    print(text)
```

It would be correct to use the [marinetraffic API](https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais-api-services).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should first scroll to that element and only after that try accessing it including getting it text.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-body1')][last()]//div")
actions.move_to_element(element).build().perform()
text = element.text
```

In case the above still not good enough you can scroll page height one time like this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(0.5)
the_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-body1')][last()]//strong").text
```

Comment: your idea is correct - when I scroll manually in Selenium and run again then I get it. But your code is not correct. You can't scroll to element because `find_element_by_xpath` can't find text `cubic` before scrolling it.

Comment: Thanks for a great help! I will try to find better locator

Comment: @furas updated the locator. Hope it will be good now

Comment: I think it will still make problem because probably it loads this `strong` as part of longer text and it would have to scroll to `div` without using `strong` - and then it will load this text with `strong`

Comment: @furas can you please try this my code? I can't do it myself since I even do not have Python with selenium on my PC :)

Comment: I test it but it doesn't work. I made working code - I scroll to `"//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']"` and search `strong` with text `cubic`. If there is no strong then I scroll to next `lazyload-wrapper`

Comment: But there are 18 elements matching `//span[@class='lazyload-wrapper']` locator... The first of them is on the top part of the screen.

Comment: I see text in second item - so I could use `[1]` to get it - but I'm not sure if it will be always on the same position.

Comment: I suggested simply scrolling one screen height down. This should work in this case, not depended on any element. At least for the current page structure.

Comment: I was thining about it but finally I skiped it. You can still create faster version.

Comment: Well, the speed delta of several milliseconds is not a problem, I think. The test reliability and stability is much important